# Regexp to get value beetween two word in string

Tags: java, android, regex

I have to get the value between two words in a string in Java, the string is like this:

```
PING 151.92.198.78 (151.92.198.78) 56(84) bytes of data. 
From 10.251.211.1: icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
```

I need to get: 10.251.211.1

This IP is always between From and icmp_seq.

How can I do this in Java?
I tried to use this code:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("From (.+?) icmp_seq=");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
matcher.find();
Log.wtf(iLinkLog, "Process output"+matcher.group(1));
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right regex will do the trick :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "PING 151.92.198.78 (151.92.198.78) 56(84) bytes of data." + "\n"
            + "From 10.251.211.1: icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*From\\s+(.*?):\\s+icmp_seq", Pattern.DOTALL);
     // pattern selects everything preceeded by "From" upto ":<space>icmp_seq"
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
10.251.211.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your line to this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("From ([0-9.]+): ");
```

---

Also, I tried to debug your regex, and found that it matches `10.251.211.1:` instead of `10.251.211.1`, as `:` is also found by `.`, i.e, I mean to say that **most of your regex is correct**, and you just need to add `:` to your regex, like:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("From (.+?): icmp_seq=");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply:

```
String ip = "From 10.251.211.1: icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded".replaceAll("From ((\\d{1,3}\\.?){4}):.+", "$1");
```

Consider the fact that you have to read line by line of your input.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get regex to work great, but personally I would use string functions. Get the index of "From ", get the index of "icmp" and get the sub-string between the two.